# Why does Hive "create external table", on S3, store data under subfolder "-ext-10000"?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive

The following Hive code has suddenly started storing data under an extra subfolder;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS folder_test;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folder_test (
    col1              STRING,
    col2          INT,
    col3              INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LOCATION 's3n://bucket_name/folder_name'
;

insert overwrite table folder_test
select col1, col2, col3 
from data_table
limit 10;
```

So rather than the data being in 's3n://bucket_name/folder_name' it is being stored under 's3n://bucket_name/folder_name/-ext-10000'.

A query over this table then results in 0 rows unless the table is redefined with the new location.

Changing the keyword "overwrite" to "into" fixes the issue, but requires us to revisit hundreds of scripts that have been working fine till recently.

We are running Hadoop 1.0.3, Hive 0.10.0 (Apache version not AWS one), on AMI 2.3.6, the only change to previously working tech stack was a move from AMI 2.2.1 which we hadn't realised before that we had made.

Why is this happening and how can we fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a regression that was introduced somewhere between AMI 2.2.1 and 2.3.6, Amazon are hoping to fix in AMI 2.3.7